# Execute records based on where clause from another table

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables, structure is given

Table 1

- schid (NOT A PRIMARY KEY)
- name
- cost
- type

Table 2

- schid (NOT A PRIMARY KEY)
- details
- oldcost

[table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os2D3.jpg)

I am unable to write a query to display records from table 2 of let suppose type A OR B (Here as you can see type field is in table 1), Here one more thing to add is that schid is not a primary key, The query which i am executing is retrieving more records than expected, I think due to join, Can i execute it without using join

The query which i am executing

```
SELECT t2.table 2
FROM table t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.table1 = t2.table2
WHERE t1.type= 'A'
```

Comment: Please add your table structure with data and query which you're trying???

Comment: Can you show what result you are expecting and what results you are getting? 

Currently, the query you provided is using columns that do not exist in the `jpg` you provided. Please show this information directly in the question, in a text format, instead of using images.